# LightHouse unused CSS do working on my page

Tags: css, font-face, lighthouse, font-family

I'm trying to improve page performance via lighthouse in Chrome dev tool, there's an opportunity to reduce unused CSS
[image: screenshot]

I find it in my project, it's imported and used on body{} with code -

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+SC:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
html,
body {
  font-family: Noto Sans SC
}
```

However, it's contradictory that if I remove it, it does change the font of my page.

I've try to remove the import and expected it doesn't change my page, but it did.

Any idea why this would happen ?

Comment: I am not clear on the question.  If you need it, then you don't remove it.

Comment: Lighthouse can only detect the CSS used by the page in its default state, anything added based on use actions/changes to the page's state/time delays etc, can appear as "unused". It's a tool that shows you things that **might** be unused, you need to confirm that yourself.

Comment: You can actually open up that google fonts stylesheet and take a look. Most of those declarations are probs outside the unicode range you're actually gonna use. Best to move away from google fonts anyhow take a look at this: https://joyofcode.xyz/using-fonts-on-the-web and only load in what you are using